# How do I create a "Licensing add-on" for my Android application?

Tags: android, apk

I see that some apps on the market come as a Free version, and a "Licensing add-on", where you can use the Free version with its limited features, or buy the license `apk` which just acts as a license key for the originally "Free" version, to unlock extra features hidden within the "free" version.

Can someone point me to an example of how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PackageManager`'s `getInstalledPackages()` or `getInstalledApplications()` to simply check if the license package is installed.

Or, if you want something a bit more sophisticated, you can give the main app and the license apk the same [user id in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid). This means that both apps can have access to your data (Shared Preferences, SQLite DB, etc). Then the license app just needs to be run once; it can store a value in the shared data indicating that the extended functionality should be enabled. The main app just needs to check this flag and alter its behaviour accordingly.

The advantage of the second approach is that the license app can be uninstalled after being run, and the main app will continue to allow the extended functionality.

Comment: i like the sound of your 2nd solution, i shall investigate it, but by the sounds of it, its just what i was looking for ..though it could be an idea to make it do periodic checks on the licence, just in-case the user A) asks for a refund after verifying the licence, B) installs a back-up of the app (including app data) on-to another device

Answer (score 3):

A better approach might be to look at [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html). That would allow you to have multiple 'products' and enable features based on what products people have bought.

The license apk approach is very simple: you know the package of the license apk and check if it is installed. If it is, you assume they have bought it, and enable 'pro' features. The disadvantage is that it is essentially an app that does nothing, and people have to keep it installed. It also gets its own rating and download count, and probably 1-star comments like 'crap, does nothing' from people who don't understand the concept.

Comment: i think i prefer the idea of allowing the user to download a "licence" apk from the market, rather than using a "in-app billing" solution, just for the simple fact that most people will trust giving money directly to google, but not directly to the app

but thats a good point about the rating and reviews of the "licence" app, but i'd just have to make it very clear in the description that it is only an add-on, and just hope that people read :P

Comment: Nobody bothers to read descriptions. In-app billing is handled by the Android Market as well, so nobody will be giving you money directly. Having one upgradable app, rather than two separate ones is far better from a usability point of view. Plus, using in-app billing gives you to chance to have different levels of upgrades if you decide on it later.It is, however, somewhat harder to implement than using an unlock app.

Comment: yes i know this, but to the user (someone who is not a dev) it will look as if your app is directly requesting money, which would likely put people off.  this solution would work well if i was to offer various stages of "upgrades", but in my case, i only require the two (free and limited, or paid and everything unlocked)

Comment: That hasn't been my experience. The payment dialog is clearly identifiable as belonging to the Android Market. But YMMV, I guess.

Comment: Has Google gave us an official recommendation to this business flow? If separate-license-app approach is accepted, then I have no comment, but if not, I'm sick to death by that practice. I haven't tried in-app billing but why so many developers use this separate-license approach???